# Python3 - Kivy RecycleView's data Dictionary succefully updated, but not phisically the Widget

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, kivy, kivy-recycleview

In a Kivy form i set 2 Recycleviews(A and B). I would add the item clicked in Recycleview A, to the RecycleView B, using a Python3 script:

```
from functools import partial
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
class B(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(B, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def doet(self,x):
        self.data.append({'text':x})
        print(self.data) #it prints correctly, so why doesn't update?
class A(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data=[{'text':'FROM HERE','on_press':partial(app.b.doet,'TO HERE')}]
class app(App):
    b=B()
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('lab.kv')
app().run()
```

'lab.kv':

```
BoxLayout:
    A:
        viewclass:'Button'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
    B:
        viewclass:'Button'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
```

My script correctly updates the Data's Dictionary, as I can see by printing it, but in RecycleView 'B' no items are phisically added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that the line:

```
b=B()
```

is creating a new instance of `B` that is unrelated to the instance of `B` that is created in your `kv`. So anything done to that new instance of `B` will have no effect on what you see on the screen.

There are many possible approaches to do what you want. Here is one:

First, add an `id` to the `B` in your `kv`:

```
B:
    id: b
```

Then, add a modify the `App` class:

```
class app(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_file('lab.kv')
        self.b = root.ids.b
        return root

    def doit(self, x):
        self.b.doet(x)
```

The above `build()` method uses the new `id` to get a reference to the correct `B` instance, and saves that reference. The `doit()` method is just an intermediary to direct the call to the correct instance of `B`.

Then modify the `A` class to use this:

```
class A(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data=[{'text':'FROM HERE','on_press':partial(App.get_running_app().doit,'TO HERE')}]
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally understand where i was wrong